# Ninject and forwarded types (as it's known in Castle Windsor)

Tags: ninject

In Castle Windsor there is a feature called forwarded types where you can have one component configuration for multiple services. For example:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(
   Component.For<Bar>().Forward<IFoo>()
      .ImplementedBy<FooBar>());
var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
var bar = container.Resolve<Bar>();
Debug.Assert(foo == bar);
```

(this Debug.Assert works 'cause Windsor by default registers things as singletons)

**How to achieve this in Ninject (version 2) ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interested to see if anyone else chimes in with a better solution, but here's an option:

Use a special IProvider when binding to do the forward:

```
public class ForwardProvider<ForwardType> : Ninject.Activation.IProvider
{
    #region IProvider Members
    public object Create( IContext context )
    {
        return context.Kernel.Get<ForwardType>();
    }

    public Type Type
    {
        get { return typeof( ForwardType ); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and then when binding:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<ITestAdapter>().To<TestAdapter>().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IAnotherAdapter>().ToProvider<ForwardProvider<ITestAdapter>>();
```

and my test:

```
var foo = kernel.Get<ITestAdapter>();
foo.Indicator = 5;

var bar = kernel.Get<TestAdapter>();
Assert.That( foo.Indicator, Is.EqualTo( 5 ) );

var baz = kernel.Get<IAnotherAdapter>();
Assert.That( baz.Indicator, Is.EqualTo( 5 ) );
```

Comment: Accepting the answer, but was hoping that it is available OOB.

Answer (score 0):

I use a slight variation of the solution presented by @dave thieben. Or rather, depending on the circumstances, I use two different approaches.

The first approach is basically the same as Dave's but without creating a separate provider.

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<FooBar>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<FooBar>());
kernel.Bind<IBar>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<FooBar>());
```

The advantage of this approach is that that we get the benefit of generic constraints. However, we need to explicitly create a binding for each forwarded type.

The second approach is a bit more elaborate and involves "hijacking" the fluent interface.

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<FooBar>().ToSelf()
    .Forward().As<IFoo>().As<IBar>()
         .InSingletonScope();
```

To accomplish this we extend the default binding builder

```
public interface IBindingForwardSyntax<T> : IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T>
{
    IBindingForwardSyntax<T> As<TService>();
}

public class BindingForwardBuilder<T> 
    : BindingBuilder<T>, IBindingForwardSyntax<T>
{
    public BindingForwardBuilder(IBinding binding, IKernel kernel) 
        : base(binding, kernel) { }

    public IBindingForwardSyntax<T> As<TForwardedType>()
    {
        Kernel.Bind<TForwardedType>().ToMethod(ctx =>
        {
            var provider = Binding.GetProvider(ctx);
            if (!typeof(TForwardedType).IsAssignableFrom(provider.Type))
            {
                string message = string.Format(
                     "Invalid binding between '{0}' and '{1}'",
                         typeof(TForwardedType), typeof(T));
                throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
            }

            return (TForwardedType)ctx.Kernel.Get(typeof(T));
        });

        return this;
    }
}
```

Finally we add an extension method.

```
public static class BindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntaxExtensions
{
    public static IBindingForwardSyntax<T> Forward<T>(
        this IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> syntax)
    {
        return new BindingForwardBuilder<T>(syntax.Binding, syntax.Kernel);
    }
}
```

The advantage of this is approach is that we only have to explicitly create one binding. The bindings for the forwarded types are implicitly created. However, this comes with a huge disadvantage: we don't get the benefit of generic constraints. Thus, it might fail during run-time if we are not careful while defining our bindings.